# How to require username + certificate with apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, svn

I'm running an apache instance on a local server and wan't to require a username plus a corresponding certificate to authenticate/authorize users for a subversion repository. That's my current server conf: What directives do I need to require a username?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin  webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerSignature On
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /opt/ssl/ServerCA/server/certs/ServerWeb.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/ssl/ServerCA/server/keys/ServerWeb.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /opt/ssl/ServerCA/CA/ServerCA.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/ssl/ServerCA/CA/ServerCA.crt
    SSLVerifyClient optional
    SSLVerifyDepth 2

    <Location /repo>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /srv/repos/svn/insec
        SSLRequireSSL
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /srv/repos/svn/insec/conf/authz
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repository"
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**edit:** added SSLCertificateChainFile so the client gets the ca cert if it is not already installed.
**edit 2:** So one last thing: how do I match a specific certificate to a username?

Comment: Umm..i maybe wrong here, but my understanding is that ssl doesn't require a username. Is username a seperate requirement for you here?

Comment: Yes, it is, but i need it so that commits to the repo are associated with a username, otherwise they appear as from "no user".

Comment: Ah that is more on svn configuration. will refresh my memory and get back...

Comment: Just for reference, i used this guide: http://www.stylesen.org/subversion_client_authentication_using_pkcs_12_based_certificates_howto on a turnkey linux appliance.

Comment: Tell me this how are the users executing the commit?? There are 2 levels of authentication involved (apache and svn). what is your svn configuration?

Comment: svn users are authenticated with an authz file.

Comment: Hmm.this might help. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#authtype

Comment: When i try i get this: [Sun May 15 14:06:11 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.36] need AuthName: /repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it working now, for further reference here my conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin  webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerSignature On
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /opt/ssl/ServerCA/server/certs/ServerWeb.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/ssl/ServerCA/server/keys/ServerWeb.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /opt/ssl/ServerCA/CA/ServerCA.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/ssl/ServerCA/CA/ServerCA.crt
    SSLVerifyClient optional
    SSLVerifyDepth 2
    SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN # that line tells apache to use the common name of the client certificate as the username, that's what i was still missing.

    <Location /repo>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /path/to/repo/
        SSLRequireSSL
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/repo/conf/authz
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, can you describe how your application works? It seems you provide repository access via apache(and therefore browser). Was wondering if it is just files storage(addition/deletion) or document editing too??

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean but it is your usual svn over https setup just with certificates and not with user/pass.